# Word to describe the structure that holds/stores a shield (and possibly other weapons)

Tags: single-word-requests, history, early-modern-english, middle-english

I am looking for a word that would used to describe either many shields, or a structure that would be used to carry them in storage.

If I look at [this medieval photo](http://media.moddb.com/images/games/1/13/12766/weaps2.jpg), there is a wooden structure on which shields and other weapons are stored.  What is the name of this structure, or similar unit?

I am open to words from any era, since I'm going to repurpose it in the context of "conveying many shields".  Search terms are helpful, since anything that I google for "sword storage" sends me to a Public Self Storage/Mini storage location.

For context, I'm using this to describe a computer software firewall I'm programming, and would like contextually relevant variable names.  Examples include:

- Umbo = The smallest, most defensive aspect of the technology
- Shield = A grouping of Umbos (it's a misappropriation but good enough, I think a shield only had a maximum of one Umbo)
- ???? =  A collection of shields that are manufactured or shipped or stored in a batch.
- ??? = A used, and therefore useless shield

Comment: This is an interesting question but I don't see any research of your own here...have you looked on any ancient weapon sites or researched any sources for antique weapon nomenclature?

Comment: I'd be very surprised if there were such a term--shields don't really call for any particular storage system. They probably just got stacked in a corner or hung on the wall. There's *armory* for a room where everything of that sort was kept for convenience in one place. If you want an invented term you could call it a *scutarium*.

Comment: Amazing! I had no idea that medieval photos existed. Would love to see a selfie by Charlemagne.

Answer (score 5):

The structure shown in your picture is what I would simply call a *[rack](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/english/rack#rack__17)*, or maybe a *stand*.

> noun
>
> 1 A framework, typically with rails, bars, hooks, or pegs, for holding
>   or storing things:
>
> From Oxford Dictionaries Online

Comment: Yes, well, a medieval rack also brings [something else](http://www.lmgtfy.com/?q=medieval+rack) to mind...

Answer (score 2):

Reeacters use ***[weapon racks](http://www.myarmoury.com/talk/viewtopic.php?p=274666)***, but there is no real evidence that they are authentic.